# How to increase setInterval timer in loop

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

Here i have a countdown script.

It decreases the number after 1 second. What i want to create is a loop where it increase the time of setInterval when decreasing the number.

For example it shows 9 copies left after 1 second, then 8 copies left after about 5 seconds, then 7 copies left after 15 seconds and so on until it reaches one.

```
var count=10;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer()
{  
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     //counter ended, do something here
     return;
  }

  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="Only " + count + " copies left! Hurry up!";
}
```

Here is my code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guraqwnd/)

Comment: You're using the wrong function. Use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a tidier way to do this, but this code achieves what you want to do (updated fiddle link at bottom):

```js
var count = 10;
var interval = 1000;
iterator();

function iterator() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="Only " + count + " copies left! Hurry up!";
  document.getElementById("interval").innerHTML="Timeout Interval: " + interval + "ms";
  count -= 1;
  interval += 1000;
  if(count>0) {
    setTimeout(iterator, interval);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="timer"></p>
<p id="interval"></p>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awenborn/zhes4mbg/)

Comment: How could I create so I can choose the next interval? This is only increasing by 1 second each  time.

Comment: How exactly do you want to choose the next interval? By user input?

Comment: With an array. I tried to create something but doesn't work as intended. https://jsfiddle.net/zhes4mbg/1/

Comment: If you just want to progressively increase the timeout interval with each iteration then you could just replace the `interval + = 1000;` line with `interval *= 2;`, which will double your interval for each iteration, or  `interval = Math.pow(interval, 2);` which will square your interval. If you really want to implement an array to manually specify the interval lengths, you can do something like this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/awenborn/c1rkc4xq/)

Comment: For the array lookup, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/awenborn/bop1xthe/) might be a better solution, where if you have more iterations than specified intervals then it simply uses the last value in the array. However a mathematical definition of interval time is much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you , this is what i needed! :)